# What is the following error in my Maven project? Access Denied

Tags: windows, file-locking

Error as shown in Marker:

> Error occured processing XML
>   'C:\Users\CHANDAN-G\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\java-blog-aggregator\target\classes\com\chandan\blog\controller\IndexController.class
>   (Access is denied)'. See Error Log for more
>   details   dispatcher-servlet.xml  /java-blog-aggregator/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF   line
>   8 Spring Beans Problem

In my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

//THIS BELOW LINE HAS THE FOLLOWING ERROR AS SHOWN BY MARKER:
<context:component-scan base-package="com.chandan.blog.controller"></context:component-scan>

<bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/defs/general.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Dependencies and Plugins In my `Pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.chandan.blog</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-blog-aggregator</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <!-- Shared version number properties -->
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <apache.tiles>3.0.5</apache.tiles>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<!--
    Core utilities used by other modules.
    Define this if you use Spring Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*)
-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.tiles}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Expression Language (depends on spring-core)
    Define this if you use Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- 
    Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core)
    Define this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) 
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>


<!--
    Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, spring-beans)
    Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, spring-beans) 
    This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection Container and is generally always defined
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, Quartz, and Freemarker integration
    Define this if you need any of these integrations
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-aop, spring-context)
    Define this if you use Spring Transactions or DAO Exception Hierarchy
    (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
    Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, and iBatis.
    (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx)
    Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans.
    (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
    Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and Portlet Environments
    (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context)
    Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
    Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-web)
    Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*)
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!--
    Support for testing Spring applications with tools such as JUnit and TestNG
    This artifact is generally always defined with a 'test' scope for the integration testing framework and unit testing stubs
-->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.3.0.M0</version>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
  <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>       
    </plugins>
  </build>
  </project>
```

Detailed Error in Console:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building java-blog-aggregator 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:9.3.0.M0:run (default-cli) @ java-blog-aggregator >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ java-blog-aggregator ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ java-blog-aggregator ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\CHANDAN-G\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\java-blog-aggregator\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/CHANDAN-G/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/java-blog-aggregator/src/main/java/com/chandan/blog/controller/IndexController.java:[7,8] error while writing com.chandan.blog.controller.IndexController: C:\Users\CHANDAN-G\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\java-blog-aggregator\target\classes\com\chandan\blog\controller\IndexController.class (Access is denied)
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.194 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-12-12T12:30:42+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/128M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project java-blog-aggregator: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/CHANDAN-G/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/java-blog-aggregator/src/main/java/com/chandan/blog/controller/IndexController.java:[7,8] error while writing com.chandan.blog.controller.IndexController: C:\Users\CHANDAN-G\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\java-blog-aggregator\target\classes\com\chandan\blog\controller\IndexController.class (Access is denied)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: This question really helped me. From the linked "duplicate of..." question it was not so clear for me that this is the case in my context. @feelingabusedandharassed please consider reopening it.

Answer (score 7):

#### File locking semantics on Windows sucks.

`'C:\Users\` tells me you are on windows.

> [ERROR]
>   /C:/Users/CHANDAN-G/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/java-blog-aggregator/src/main/java/com/chandan/blog/controller/IndexController.java:[7,8]
>   **error while writing** com.chandan.blog.controller.IndexController: **C:\Users\CHANDAN-G\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\java-blog-aggregator\target\classes\com\chandan\blog\controller\IndexController.class**
>   (Access is denied)

There is an application that has a file lock on that file. It is trying to over-write that file and it can not because another process has it locked. Most likely a running JVM since it is a `.class` file. It is as plain and simple as that.

Close all the applications - Windows Explorer and your IDE are applications - and try again.

Comment: I have included Entire Error Messages that I obtained in Console by editing the Question. Thank you. Except Chrome and Spring Tool Suite, I have not opened any other application. I even checked in Task Manager also.

Comment: something has that file locked, this is **not** a maven or java problem it has nothing to do with spring or xml! Do not spam the tags. This is specifically a Windows problem, regardless of what you think something has that file locked, not all processes show up in the "task manager" and file explorer counts as an "application".

Comment: Can I know what is the solution? Marker Error is for this line of code:
<context:component-scan base-package="com.chandan.blog.controller"></context:component-scan>

Comment: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project java-blog-aggregator: Compilation failure